Max 2d-Array Size in minizinc with or-tools CP-SAT
define 2d-array as following in minizinc :
array[1..400,1..400] of var int : en_b ;

run with Or-tools CP-SAT 9.11 as backend ,
get error with "=====UNKNOWN=====" .
PS. 9.11 is default with minizinc
run with or tools 9.6 as backend ,
run success with "=========="
so is there any size limited with CP-SAT ? or any other problem (solver define? )

is this the full model ?

full model also have other constraint ； only with this define , code can be compiled but error with "=====UNKNOWN=====" .

We check for potential overflows and we are very conservative
The exact message is:
Invalid model: The sum of all variable domains do not fit on an int64_t. This is needed to prevent overflows.
This is because you are creating 400*400 variables, and the default max bound for an int domain is 1<<50.
The best solution is to replace int by -BigNumber..BigNumber with BigNumber large enough and not too large.
In practice, any CP solver benefits from bounded variables.
Another solution is to use a flag to specify the max range of an int variable when converting from flatzinc to CP-SAT:
The trick is to pass --fz_int_max=1000000000
Unfortunately, in 9.11, you will need to patch the cp-sat.msc to change the extra flags section:
  "extraFlags": [
    ["--params", "Provide parameters interpreted as a text SatParameters proto", "string", ""],
    ["--fz_int_max", "Provide the maximum value for integer variables", "int", "1125899906842624"]
  ],


Thanks a lot for your help . With edit with cp-sat.msc , it is worked in Minizinc IDE 。 but when I call minzinc from python with  it not worked .  "async for result in model_instance.solutions(intermediate_solutions=True,processes=run_core_count,timeout=runTimeLimit,fz_int_max=1125899906842624):"   .  What should i do in python

Infro from Debug with Pyhon 。 when Solver.lookup("com.google.ortools.sat",refresh=True) finished , the extraFlags is right with solver 。 When model_instance.solutions(...) , the temp mpc file was created with  "--fz_int_max": 1125899906842624  inside the mzn_agIWjG.mpc . but the result is still ======unkonw=======
